# Does Mary Stone have a beard?

Tags: dwarves, cover-art, dwarf-for-hire

I've not gotten a hold of [Rune Service: Dwarf for Hire](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/35131594-rune-service) yet, but I have noticed the two covers have a conflicting depiction for Mary Stone, the main character.

[image: Mary Stone on the cover of an earlier edition, with a beard][image: Mary Stone on the cover of the later edition, without a beard].

Obviously the production value between the two is quite different, but I'm trying to assess which is more accurate to the character depiction in text (i.e. I'm not assuming that the earlier cover is more accurate)

Comment: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CoversAlwaysLie

Comment: @Valorum only one of these is a lie...

Comment: The one with the professional model on the cover is the lie; https://www.deviantart.com/frostalexis/gallery/54473760/alexis-s-book-cover-store

Comment: That author is on Goodreads. You might want to ask them why they went with a cover that so wildly diverges from their vision of the character (e.g. not a dwarf, not bearded)

Comment: @Giacomo1968 my guess is that's the author's or a friend's piece of art. Opening with "Why was the amateurish cover swapped for an inaccurate one?" Is not the friendliest way to start a conversation...

Comment: @AncientSwordRage - The cover creator appears to specialise in making generic-looking fantasy book covers.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 my point is saying something is "amateurish" or "ugly as sin" isn't nice regardless of whether the artist hears it or not

Answer (score 22):

She has a beard

> No way in heck was I going to admit that my prospective date had
> canceled the exact second he found out that the profile pictures
> hadn’t been some strange practical joke. **It’s the bitter truth that
> your average red-blooded American male (or any man for that matter …
> any woman either) just isn’t into four-foot tall bearded women.**

and

> I let out a double sigh as I leaned my chin against my fist, **my silky, red beard engulfing my hand.** I had spent four hours this morning washing, shampooing, conditioning, and brushing the albatross hanging off my chin, determined to follow that old chestnut of making a weakness a strength. It’s not like I could shave it, not when it grew back within an hour.

and

> Regardless of what might actually be, he was some weird alien elf and **I was some strange bearded dwarf lady.** If we weren’t freaks, I didn’t know what was.

and

> Instead, his voice was soft and respectful as he said, **“How could I not be seeking out anyone other than yourself, Lady Stone? With curls of fire and a beard to match,** you have the courage of a lioness and the strength of a dragon. There would be no other Dwarf I would seek out who could better provide me the stalwart aid I need in my dark hours or by whose radiance I would set my course too.”